# How to get a number from HTML form and pass it to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to calculate Body Mass Index by receiving Weight and Height from HTML form and passing it to JavaScript code by .getElementById();. But, as far as I understand, type of data received from form is "string" and I need to receive a "number". How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` should help you

Comment: yes or multiple with 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parseInt().

```
var a = "10";
var b = parseInt(a);
```

See : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementById("whatever").value;

// You can use any 3
+a; // Unary Operator
parseInt(a, 10); // parseInt with radix 10
Number(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use function **parseInt(string)** that Convert string into int .Now in your senario :-
var weight_str = document.getElementByID("weight");
var weight_int = parseInt(weight_str);

this will give you the result.